# Is $f(t)=O(t^{\alpha})$ with $f$ continuous equivalent to $f(t)<K.t^{\alpha}$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function. Is $f(t)=O(t^{\alpha})$ equivalent to $f(t)\lt K.t^{\alpha}$ almost everywhere for some absolute positive constant $K$?

Answer (score 0):

See the definition of Big O in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

If by "almost everywhere" you mean that $\exists \: t_0$ such that for all $t\geq t_0$, and if you use $|f(t)|$ in stead of $f(t)$ then yes, it is correct.

Comment: By "almost everywhere" I mean on $(t_{0},\infty)\setminus J$, where $J$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: The function $f$ is continuous, so a measure $0$ set won't really make a meaningful difference. Up to increasing $K$, everything stays the same even if we remove $J$.

Comment: That was actually the goal of my question. Thanks for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify if you are interested in the regime $t\to\infty$ or in $t\to0$.

Let me take the regime $t\to\infty$ as an example.
By definition, $f(t)=O(t^\alpha)$ as $t\to\infty$ means that
there is $T$ and $C$ such that
$$
|f(t)|\leq C|t|^\alpha
\qquad\textrm{whenever}\quad
|t|>T.
$$
So it does not need to be bounded almost everywhere. For example, the function $f(t)=\frac1t$ satisfies 
$f(t)=O(1)$ as $t\to\infty$ but it blows up as $t\to0$.